# A session is created for each request from another domain

Tags: c#, angular, session, asp.net-core, cart

I use ASP.NET Core Web API 2.0 and Angular 5.

I need use session for cart. When I send requests from swagger, server use one session on all requests, when I send request from Angular (different domain), server create new session on each request.

I use CORS:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

And added it above CartController

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
```

Also I initialize session

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            if (!context.Session.Keys.Contains("Cart"))
            {
                context.Session.Set<Cart>("Cart", new Cart());
            }
            else
            {
                context.Session.Get<Cart>("Cart");
            }
        });
```

And added services

```
        services.AddRouting();
        services.AddScoped(SessionCart.GetCart);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        });
```

SessionCart

```
        public static Cart GetCart(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        ISession session = ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>(services)?.HttpContext.Session;
        SessionCart cart = session?.Get<SessionCart>("Cart") ?? new SessionCart();
        cart.Session = session;
        return cart;
    }

    public override void AddItem(DishModel product, int quantity)
    {
        base.AddItem(product, quantity);
        Session.Set("Cart", this);
    }
```

How I can fix the problem?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Are third party cookies enabled?

Comment: I use google chrome, Block third-party cookies is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an API is stateless, which means that each request is separate. As such, you are not going to be able to keep anything on the API side, in "session".

What you want to do you can achieve in other ways and the particular solution  depends on your requirements.

One way would be to keep track of your Cart on the JavaScript side and use the API to store anything you need. You could let the user add / remove / do whatever they want and when they submit then you send the contents of the cart to the api in one go.

Some systems I worked on required to keep track of every operation on the cart, to report on items / abandonment rates, stuff like that. If that is the case then you can create a cart initially, keep track of its id coming back from the api / database and then issue a request every time something is added or removed. The id of the cart is used to keep track of the data and then you don't need to keep anything in session.

So, pick your poison, depending on your requirements.